# vsftpd is failing in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, vsftpd

I have just setup vsftpd and unable to start the server.

I have tried to change the `listen` parameter from `yes` to `no`, but without any difference.

Most guides mention xinetd or inetd, but there are no such applications in my distro?

When `no`:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: not configured for standalone, must be started from inetd
```

When `yes`:

```
$ service vsftpd restart
Stopping FTP server: vsftpd.
Starting FTP server: vsftpd.

$ vsftpd
500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

$ netstat -npl
... 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30129/vsftpd
```

Comment: How do you start the service?

Comment: I have updated my question. I simply use `service vstpd start`. When listen is set to `no` i am not quite sure how to start the service as i do not have xinetd.

Comment: As in the answer vsftpd is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by `netstat`, `vsftpd` is actually running. `service restart` is enough to start it, you don't need to run `vsftpd` separately (and as you found out, you can't).

If you want to use an `inetd` daemon instead, there are a number of possibilities in Wheezy:

- [xinetd](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/xinetd)
- [inetutils-inetd](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/inetutils-inetd)
- [openbsd-inetd](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/openbsd-inetd)

Comment: When i try to connect i constantly get this error in my FTP client `Error -203: miscellaneous error occurred while trying to login to the host`, although the log shows `Wed Apr 29 14:42:03 2015 [pid 1] [testuser] OK LOGIN: Client "42.114.234.34"`. Obviously it is accepting my username and password as i have tried to enter a wrong password. Lack of configuration?

Comment: Does the target folder exist? You should update your question since your real problem doesn't have much to do with starting `vsftpd`...